# Migration - Changing IP of A Record in DNS with Zero downtime

Tags: api, amazon-web-services, dns, migration, migrate

I am migrating my API from a provider to AWS.

I have a TTL of 30 seconds for the A Record, so I know that for 30 seconds the old ip will be fetched by the browser etc.

I want to be notified at the starting of this 30 seconds TTL in order to stop serving new api requests and make the migration a zero error one.

How can i get to know the exact moment of switch from previous provider ip to AWS ip?

Comment: You have **no** guarantee that all caches honor such a low TTL, even if they will be outside of the standard. Also, why do you want to stop providing service on the old IP? Just continue to do so and naturally you will see the trafic vanishes and then you will be able to decommission the IP. As for when the IP change is visible (on authoritative nameservers), it all depends on your DNS provider. However this is not a programming related question so you are off topic here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot in any practical sense.

You are misunderstanding how DNS works. DNS consists of a globally replicated system that resolves DNS names to IP addresses (at its basic level). How long does this replication take, varies. Can I count on replication, eventually. Can I manage or control this replication, no.

The TTL is the Time To Live value. This is a recommendation not a requirement. This value is not respected by a lot of DNS resolvers. A typical TTL is measure in hours, days or weeks. Not seconds. Many clients will just ignore a short TTL.

What is the best practices approach if you want near zero downtime? You replicate your services so that both the old DNS enteries and the new DNS entries work. Expect this to take several days not several seconds.

If you are also moving your records (registration) to AWS then add a day or two extra. All of the registrars will tell you that the process can take days to finalize. There is also the risk (which has happened to me several times moving away from Network Solutions to Route 53) that the transfer request is revoked at a later date. Even after paying AWS and renewing the records, the domain jumped back to Network Solutions for some "unknown" reason weeks later.

In my best practices I inform my customers to plan on 30 days for mission critical systems.

Comment: To be precise, it is not exactly "replication" (even if everyone says that) but rejuvenation, because the changes are not pushed top down, they are picked by recursive resolvers when they decide they need the data (empty cache or expired TTL).

Comment: *This is a recommendation not a requirement.* I disagree. It is the maximum time a record should stay in cache, and resolvers ought to respect that (as a maximum, so they can requery before). In practice it is true that they are some resolvers that clamp this value, specifically when too small, but one can argue they are against the standard.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek - In theory I agree with you. However, we have to build our systems for the real world. If part of a standard is ignored (on purpose or by accident or by bug), we have to accept that fact and work around it. To build an enterprise system based upon the behavior of TTL values is a recipe for disappointment at best.

Comment: I am not saying exactly the opposite. A resolver clamping the value to a maximum is creating more network traffic but poses no harm, but resolvers that clamps too short values are indeed going against the publisher wishes and hence pose a problem. But at the same time people using very short TTL like 30 seconds or even 5 or 1 second as sometimes seen, may not exactly understand the DNS and how this is used, so I can feel some sympathy to resolvers trying to protect their own infrastructure.

Comment: As for "*that the transfer request is revoked at a later date.*" you then seem to speak here about a registrar transfer, not a change of authoritative nameservers. They are orthogonal except of course if you use your registrar as DNS provider which has its own drawbacks and benefits.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek - just an example of what happens in the real world. In several cases when the transfer was rejected (pulled back) the old DNS entries went into effect. If you don't plan for failure you risk failure. In regards to Route 53 being both your registrar and DNS provider, I recommend that to all my customers who use AWS.

Comment: Let's close this thread. We are now off topic for the question at hand. I appreciate your input on DNS. You have a good understanding where most people just ignore DNS entirely.

Comment: Mixing registrar transfer and DNS change is not a good idea anyway. Especially if your registrar is your DNS provider, which is a situation I recommend against most of the time. But I will stop commenting now, per your wish :-)